# How to ask multiple questions with multiple choices in an E-Mail in Microsoft Power-Automate

Tags: email, power-automate, approval

I'm aware that there are approval workflows that involve a question with a choice of options. I would like to have several questions answered in one email.

I work in a big company and because many emails are received per day, I do not want to start several approval workflows but only one. My project is about the registration of new employees.

I would like to query whether:

- the data of the new employee is correct (approve/reject),
- what type of ID is required (permanent ID/visitor ID) and
- whether the new employee needs photo permission for construction work, for example (yes/no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Adaptive Card](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) where you can ask multiple input in email.

Reference Links

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiQ6tHGwNVg
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-automate-to-collect-responses-with-adaptive-cards-on-microsoft-teams/